# How to use ffmpeg on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, video, ffmpeg

I have to use the following command for ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i "Video.mp4" -map 0:1 "AudioWithVocalfromStreamOne.mp3" -map 0:2 "AudioWithoutVocalfromStreamTwo.mp3"
```

I have successfully installed ffmpeg on my mac. I tried using [FFMPEGWrapper](https://github.com/OpenWatch/FFmpegWrapper), but it doesn't seem to take any such parameters for using "map".

I need to know how to extract the streams from a video. I already have access to the streams, as server side is providing it to me using ffprobe at their end.

Comment: iOS or macOS ? Am I missing something? It's better to upload video to server & convert, instead of converting in iOS, as the phone has limited computing power.

Comment: I am doing it on iOS. Basically I would be downloading a video from server, extracting the audio file without vocals from the video, and use it in Karaoke. Initially I used to download all the files from server. Downloading just the video would reduce my downloading time.

Comment: Did you try the `(NSDictionary *)options` in the main wrapper function?

Comment: It uses this "options" dictionary only to fetch values for "kFFmpegInputFormatKey" and "kFFmpegOutputFormatKey" which it uses in "av_find_input_format" this function. And I am not sure what values should I provide there, and whether they would be useful to me for extracting the streams from the given video.

Comment: You can get  FFMPEGWrapper source code and modify it to work with several output files like in your command line example with map parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best method of using FFMpeg for IOS is the MobileFFMpeg Library.

Here is the source:
<strike>https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg</strike>

superseded by FFmpegKit – https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/236757/user237419

It is available as a pod

iOS

pod 'ffmpeg-kit-ios-full', '~> 4.5.1'

macOS

pod 'ffmpeg-kit-macos-full', '~> 4.5.1'

tvOS

pod 'ffmpeg-kit-tvos-full', '~> 4.5.1'

Make sure to get appropriate FFMpeg license. Different licenses have different libs

License to choose from:

min

min-gpl

https

https-gpl

audio

video

full

full-gpl

Comment: is apple rejecting gpl licenses app?

Comment: superseded by [FFmpegKit](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit)