# How do I use the CLI interface of FFMpeg from a static build?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg

I have added this (https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script) version of ffmpeg to my project. I can't see the entry point to the library in the headers included.

How do I get access to the same text command based system that the stand alone application has, or an equivalent?

I would also be happy if someone could point me towards documentation that allows you to use FFmpeg without the command line interface.

This is what I am trying to execute (I have it working on windows and android using the CLI version of ffmpeg)

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i snap%03d.jpg -itsoffset 00:00:03.23333 -itsoffset 00:00:05 -i soundEffect.WAV -c:v libx264 -vf fps=30 -pix_fmt yuv420p result.mp4
```

Comment: so what is your use case here for the ios app ? and you just want ffmpeg to convert (wav) files to video(mp4) files with cropped audio from the audio file ??

Comment: Its converting a series of still images to a video file, and adding audio to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you can build ffmpeg library including the ffmpeg binary's code (ffmpeg.c). Only thing to care about is to rename the function `main(int argc, char **argv)`, for example, to `ffmpeg_main(int argc, char **argv)` - then you can call it with arguments just like you're executing ffmpeg binary. Note that `argv[0]` should contain program name, just `"ffmpeg"` should work.

The same approach was used in the library [VideoKit](https://github.com/inFullMobile/videokit-ffmpeg-android) for Android.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, I'll give it a try tomorrow. That VideoKit for Android looks like exactly what I wanted, but for iOS! Unfortunate.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't got round to this yet

Comment: @deek0146, it would be good if you can detail what steps you took to achieve the same

Comment: I will when I get round to it; other priorities have emerged. I just accepted this answer because my bounty was going to expire.

Comment: Do you know how I turn the make project into an xcode project? I have the make project building, but it builds into an executable which I don't need, and changing the name of the main function causes it to not compile. I can't find an xcode project that contains ffmpeg.c anywhere.

Comment: Probably just create an empty project and add all the sources into it?

Comment: It has a lot of sources which are duplicates and unused based on the output of the configure script.

Comment: I would use some instruction like this: https://gist.github.com/phucnm/4fe443ee17a1e0773563 including first ffmpeg.c into a static library target and renaming `main` function inside

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you have to use your compiled FFmpeg library in your code.

What you are looking for is exactly the code providing by FFmpeg documentation [libavformat/output-example.c](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/output-example_8c-source.html) (that mean `AVFormat` and `AVCodec` FFmpeg's libraries in general).

Stackoverflow is not a "do it for me please" platform. So I prefer explaining here what you have to do, and I will try to be precise and to answer all your questions.

I assume that you already know how to link your compiled (static or shared) library to your Xcode project, this is not the topic here.

So, let's talk about this code. It creates a video (containing video stream and audio stream randomly generated) based on a duration. You want to create a video based on a picture list and sound file. Perfect, there are only three main modifications you have to do:

- The end condition is not reaching a duration, but reaching the end of your file list (In code there is already a `#define STREAM_NB_FRAMES` you can use to iterate over all you frames).
- Replace the dummy `void fill_yuv_image` by your own method that load and decode image buffer from file.
- Replace the dummy `void write_audio_frame` by your own method that load and decode the audio buffer from your file.

(you can find "how to load audio file content" example [on documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decoding__encoding_8c-source.html) starting at line 271, easily adaptable for video content regarding documentation)

In this code, comparing to your CLI, you can figure out that:

- `const char *filename;` in the main should be you output file *"result.mp4"*.
- `#define STREAM_FRAME_RATE 25` (replace it by *30*).
- For MP4 generation, video frames will be encoded in H.264 by default (in this code, the GOP is 12). So no need to precise libx264.
- `#define STREAM_PIX_FMT PIX_FMT_YUV420P` represents your desired *yuv420p* decoding format.

Now, with these official examples and related documentation, you can achieve what you desire. Be careful that there is some differences between FFmpeg's version in these examples and current FFmpeg's version. For example:

```
st = av_new_stream(oc, 1); // line 60
```

Could be replaced by:

```
st = avformat_new_stream(oc, NULL);
st->id = 1;
```

Or:

```
if (avcodec_open(c, codec) < 0) { // line 97
```

Could be replaced by:

```
if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
```

Or again:

```
dump_format(oc, 0, filename, 1); // line 483
```

Could be replaced by:

```
av_dump_format(oc, 0, filename, 1);
```

Or `CODEC_ID_NONE` by `AV_CODEC_ID_NONE`... etc.

Ask your questions, but you got all the keys! :)

Answer (score 0):

MobileFFMpeg is an easy to use pod for the purpose. Instructions on how to use MobileFFMpeg at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59325680/1466453

MobileFFMpeg gives a very simple method for translating ffmpeg commands to your IOS objective-c program.

Virtually all ffmpeg commands and switches are supported. However you have to get the pod with appropriate license. e.g min-gpl will not give you features of libiconv. libiconv is convered in vidoe, gpl and full-gpl licenses.

Please highlight if you have specific issues regarding use of MobileFFMpeg